# Unable to upload file to S3 using Lambda written in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I'm trying to upload a file (pdf/jpg) using a Lambda function written in NodeJS by triggering the request from PostMan but the code is not working at all. How should I apply the file? Is it in base64 format or using the type as 'File' in the body?

Here is my defective code:-

```
        'use-strict'

const AWS = require("aws-sdk");

const logger = require('./logger').logger;

const moment = require('moment');

const fileType = ('file-type');

const { Buffer } = require('buffer');

//const { fileTypeFromFile } = 'file-type';

const ddbTable = process.env.RUNTIME_DDB_TABLE_FREE_USER_DOCUMENT;

const s3TempBucket = process.env.RUNTIME_S3_TEMP_BUCKET;

const s3 = new AWS.S3();

const getFile = (fileMime, buffer, userId) => {
  let fileExt = fileMime.ext;
  let hash = sha1(new Buffer(new Date().toString()));
  let now = moment().format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');

  let filePath = hash + '/';
  let fileName = unixTime(now) + '.' + fileExt;
  let fileFullName = filePath + fileName;
  let fileFullPath = s3TempBucket + userId + fileFullName;

  const params = {
    Body: buffer,
    Bucket: s3TempBucket,
    Key: fileName
  };

  let uploadFile = {
    size: buffer.toString('ascii').length,
    type: fileMime.mime,
    name: fileName,
    fullPath: fileFullPath
  }

  return {
    'params': params,
    'uploadFile': uploadFile
  }
}

exports.lambdaHandler = (event, context) => {
  logger.info("Event::", event);
  logger.info('Uploading file to bucket::', s3TempBucket);

  let body, data;
  let statusCode = 200;
  const headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Headers': 'Content-Type',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': '*'
  };

  //const user = event.body.user;
  let request = event.body;
  let base64String = request.base64String;
  
  //let buffer = Buffer.from(JSON.stringify(base64String), 'base64');
  let buffer = new Buffer(base64String, 'base64');
  let fileMime = fileType(buffer);
  logger.info(fileMime);

  if (fileMime === null) {
    return context.fail('String supplied is not file type');
  }

  //let file = getFile(fileMime, buffer, user.id);
  let file = getFile(fileMime, buffer, 'b06eb6f4-0ff0-5cb5-a41c-e000af66c8e9');
  let params = file.params;

  try {
    //await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      s3.putObject(params, (err, results) => {
        if (err) reject(err);
        else {
          console.log(results);
          body = results;
          resolve(results)
        }
      });
   // });

  } catch (err) {
    logger.info(err);
    statusCode = 400;
    body = err.message;
    return err;
  } finally {
    body = JSON.stringify(data);
  }

  return {
    statusCode,
    body,
    headers
  };

}
```

Following error is coming on CloudWatch at this line `const buffer = Buffer.from(selectedFile, 'base64')`:-

```
2022-01-30T07:20:33.019Z    4c916aca-93e2-4846-84a2-d7f048f1de52    ERROR   Invoke Error    
{
    "errorType": "TypeError",
    "errorMessage": "The first argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, ArrayBuffer, or Array or an Array-like Object. Received undefined",
    "code": "ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE",
    "stack": [
        "TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The first argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer, ArrayBuffer, or Array or an Array-like Object. Received undefined",
        "    at new NodeError (internal/errors.js:322:7)",
        "    at Function.from (buffer.js:334:9)",
        "    at Runtime.exports.lambdaHandler [as handler] (/var/task/app.js:62:18)",
        "    at Runtime.handleOnce (/var/runtime/Runtime.js:66:25)"
    ]
}
```

From Postman, I'm trying to send the document (in the base64 format) in the **file** attribute and name of the document in the **name** attribute as shown in the below screenshot:-

[image]

[image]

```
    info: Event:: 
{
    "body": "{\n    \"base64String\": \"/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wCEAAcHBwcIBwgJCQgMDAsMDBEQDg4QERoSFBIUEhonGB0YGB0YJyMqIiAiKiM+MSsrMT5IPDk8SFdOTldtaG2Pj8ABBwcHBwgHCAkJCAwMCwwMERAODhARGhIUEhQSGicYHRgYHRgnIyoiICIqIz4xKysxPkg8OTxIV05OV21obY+PwP/CABEICHAPAAMBIgACEQEDEQH/xAAcAAEAAgMBAQEAAAAAAAAAAAAABwgBBQYEAwL/2gAI
```

Comment: Reading the error message it appears that `event.body.file` is `undefined`. You should print `event` to check if it really contains what you are looking for. Maybe `console.log(JSON.stringify(event))`.

Comment: @Jens, I have attached the screenshot of the request in the question above. The event object is not empty. I'm converting the document in the base64 format and then triggering it.

Comment: That's what you are sending to the API in postman. But that is not necessarily what your Lambda receives. So you need to output the `event` your Lambda got and inspect that to see if there is actually a file in that event.

Comment: @jens, I have added a new screenshot/log of the event object which is getting captured at the CloudWatch side. Can you please point me in the right direction where I'm making the mistake? Thanks

Comment: In this statement, base64String is coming as undefined   let buffer = new Buffer(base64String, 'base64');  Somehow, I believe, there should be some kind of awaiting process on this line so that Buffer object can be read completely as I can clearly see event object is not empty at all when triggered from Postman